# How do you move all files (including hidden) from one directory to another?

Tags: shell, wildcards, dot-files, mv

How do I move all files in a directory (including the hidden ones) to another directory?

For example, if I have a folder "Foo" with the files ".hidden" and "notHidden" inside, how do I move both files to a directory named "Bar"?  The following does not work, as the ".hidden" file stays in "Foo".

```
mv Foo/* Bar/
```

Try it yourself.

```
mkdir Foo
mkdir Bar
touch Foo/.hidden
touch Foo/notHidden
mv Foo/* Bar/
```

Comment: [Linux: How to move all files from current directory to upper directory ?](http://superuser.com/questions/62141/linux-how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory)

Comment: Bah, I knew I should have refreshed the answers before typing mine up.  Very helpful link.

Comment: Sadly, this question ended up here because I said on SO that it should move here or SU, so of course it moved here when there was a duplicate on SU already :)

Comment: Personally, I think *nix specific questions and answers should be off-topic on SU. With the current rules we end up with tons of content collisions between the two - like this question.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Quick answers first; see below for more in-depth discussion and documentation links for bash, ksh93 and zsh.

#### Zsh

```
mv Foo/*(DN) Bar/
```

or

```
setopt glob_dots null_glob
mv Foo/* Bar/
```

Case and underscores are ignored in the option name. `set -o` can also be used like in Korn/POSIX-like shells and `dotglob` (DotGlob, DOT_GLOB...) is also supported for compatibility with the GNU shell (bash).

#### Bash

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
mv Foo/* Bar/
```

#### Ksh93

If you know the directory is not empty:

```
FIGNORE='.?(.)'
mv Foo/* Bar/
```

#### Fish

If you know the directory is not empty:

```
mv Foo/{.,}* Bar/
```

#### Standard (POSIX) sh

```
for x in Foo/* Foo/.[!.]* Foo/..?*; do
  if [ -e "$x" ]; then mv -- "$x" Bar/; fi
done
```

If you're willing to let the `mv` command return an error status even though it succeeded, it's a lot simpler:

```
mv Foo/* Foo/.[!.]* Foo/..?* Bar/
```

#### GNU find and GNU mv

```
find Foo/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -t Bar/ -- {} +
```

#### Standard find

```
find Foo/. ! -name . -prune -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$@" "$0"' ../Bar/ {} +
```

---

Here's more detail about controlling whether dot files are matched in bash, ksh93 and zsh.

#### Bash

Set the [`dotglob` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin).

```
$ echo *
none zero
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo *
..two .one none zero
```

There's also the more flexible [`GLOBIGNORE` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-GLOBIGNORE-194), which you can set to a colon-separated list of wildcard patterns to ignore. If unset (the default setting), the shell behaves as if the value was empty if `dotglob` is set, and as if the value was `.*` if the option is unset. See [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) in the manual. The pervasive directories `.` and `..` are always omitted, unless the `.` is matched explicitly by the pattern.

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='n*'
$ echo *
..two .one zero
$ echo .*
..two .one
$ unset GLOBIGNORE
$ echo .*
. .. ..two .one
$ GLOBIGNORE=.:..
$ echo .*
..two .one
```

#### Ksh93

Set the [`FIGNORE` variable](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#Parameter%20Expansion). If unset (the default setting), the shell behaves as if the value was `.*`. To ignore `.` and `..`, they must be matched explicitly (the manual in ksh 93s+ 2008-01-31 states that `.` and `..` are always ignored, but this does no longer correctly describe the actual behavior; *edit* [that was fixed since](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/11)).

```
$ echo *
none zero
$ FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
$ echo *
..two .one none zero
$ FIGNORE='n*'
$ echo *
. .. ..two .one zero
```

You can include dot files in a [pattern](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#File%20Name%20Generation) by matching them explicitly.

```
$ unset FIGNORE
$ echo @(*|.[^.]*|..?*)
..two .one none zero
```

To have the expansion come out empty if the directory is empty, use the `N` pattern matching option: `~(N)@(*|.[^.]*|..?*)` or `~(N:*|.[^.]*|..?*)`.

#### Zsh

Set the [`dot_glob` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-DOT_005fGLOB).

```
% echo *
none zero
% setopt dot_glob
% echo *
..two .one none zero
```

`.` and `..` are never matched, even if the pattern matches the leading `.` explicitly.

```
% echo .*
..two .one
```

You can include dot files in a specific pattern with the `D` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
% echo *(D)
..two .one none zero
```

Add the `N` glob qualifier to make the expansion come out empty in an empty directory: `*(DN)`.

---

Note: you may get filename expansion results in different orders
(e.g., `none` followed by `.one` followed by `..two`)
based on your settings of the `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_ALL`, and `LANG` variables.

Comment: Why `nullglob`? It would make more sense to abort the `mv` command (like fish, csh/tcsh, zsh (without `(N)`) do, or bash with failglob) than running a `mv /Bar/` command which makes little sense.

Comment: I'd say your GLOBIGNORE description is inaccurate and misleading. Setting GLOBIGNORE to a non-empty value turns on dotglob and makes that `.` and `..` are never matched (like in other sensible shells like zsh, fish, pdksh and derivatives) even if you turn dotglob back off afterwards. (`GLOBIGNORE=:; shopt -u dotglob; echo .*` won't output `.` and `..`). setting GLOBIGNORE to `.:..` or `.` or `:` have the same effect.

Comment: `ksh93` always ignoring `.` and `..` seems to have been broken in between `ksh93k+` (where it worked) and `ksh93m` (where it no longer works). Note that it's bad in that `ksh93` will take the value of FIGNORE from the environment, so a `FIGNORE='!(..)'` env var for instance can create havoc.

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere on the (DN) option in zsh? can't find it.

Comment: @Plumpie It's two glob qualifiers. There's a link to the documentation in my answer.

Comment: **My notes** The ZSH command `mv Foo/*(DN) Bar/` will only move the contents of `Foo/`inside `Bar/` including the hidden files but without the `Foo/` directory.

Comment: I cried. So beautiful. Thanks for making this world better with such a high quality answer!

Answer (score 33):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob
mv Foo/* Bar/
```

#### From `man bash`

> **dotglob** If set, bash includes
>   filenames beginning with a '.' in the
>   results of pathname expansion.

Comment: With the caveat that this command returns an error code if the directory was empty (even though the command actually performed as intended).

Comment: @Gilles, the error will then be from `mv` complaining that that file called `Foo/*` doesn't exist. Interestingly, if `Foo` is searchable, but not readable, and there is a file called `*` in there, you'll get no error, that file will be moved, but not the other ones in the directory. `bash` has a `failglob` option so it behaves more like `zsh`, `fish` or `csh`/`tcsh` and abort the command with an error when a glob cannot be expanded instead of that bogus behaviour  of leaving the glob as-is.

Answer (score 21):

A simple way to do this in `bash` is

```
mv {Foo/*,Foo/.*} Bar/
```

But this will also move directories.

If you want to move all files including hidden but don't want to move any directory you can use a for loop and test.

`for i in $(ls -d {Foo/*,Foo/.*});do test -f $i && mv -v $i Bar/; done;`

Comment: The easiest solution because it needs not to remember a second command : ) Thanks.

Comment: For even easier use, could also be `mv foo/{*,.*} bar/`

Comment: that's nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `find`:

```
find Foo/ -type f -exec mv -t Bar/ {} \+
```

The `-type f` restricts the find command to finding files.  You should investigate the `-type`, `-maxdepth`, and `-mindepth` options of `find` to customize your command to account for subdirectories. Find has a lengthy but very helpful [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: That only moves the regular files in `Foo/`, not subdirectories and other files.

Answer (score 4):

I find that this works well for bash and there's no need to change shell options

```
mv sourcedir/{*,.[^.]*} destdir/
```

EDIT:

So as G-man stated, my original answer is not posix compliant and is pretty much the same as  ndemou’s answer above with one change, which is to use brace expansion to create lists of strings which are then acted on. This just means you don't need to `cd` into the source directory. Not that big a change really, but it is different.

example: let's say you have the following layout already.

```
 $ tree -a
.
├── destdir
└── sourcedir
    ├── ..d1
    ├── ..d2
    ├── ..double
    ├── file-1
    ├── file-2
    ├── .hidden-1
    ├── .hidden-2
    ├── ...t1
    └── ...t2
```

The original question only mentioned hidden files with a single period, but let's say there are some with two or more periods at the start of the name. You can just add in an additional expression into the braces. We can then execute

```
mv sourcedir/{*,.[!.]*,..?*} destdir/
```

This gets expanded to the following:

```
mv sourcedir/file-1 sourcedir/file-2 sourcedir/.hidden-1 sourcedir/.hidden-2 sourcedir/..d1 sourcedir/..d2 sourcedir/..double sourcedir/...t1 sourcedir/...t2 destdir/
```

You should now see all files located in **destdir**:

```
 $ tree -a
.
├── destdir
│   ├── ..d1
│   ├── ..d2
│   ├── ..double
│   ├── file-1
│   ├── file-2
│   ├── .hidden-1
│   ├── .hidden-2
│   ├── ...t1
│   └── ...t2
└── sourcedir
```

You can do some pretty cool things with braces in bash with even more additions in 4.x. Check out [bash-hackers](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) for some nifty examples.

Comment: This basically duplicates [ndemou’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6393/80216#402856) except you added curly braces (without explaining them).  But (1) your answer doesn’t match files whose names begin with **`..`**, and (2) to be [POSIX compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13), you should use `!` instead of `^`; i.e., ```{*,.[!.]*}```.

Comment: @G-Man, sorry about that. So you are correct and my bad for not seeing ndemou's response. They are pretty much the same thing. 1. thank you for pointing out my version is not posix compliant. 2. I'm using the brace expansion to create lists of strings which the shell will then use to perform an action on. This also means I don't need to `cd` into the source directory to act on the files or write out the same file paths over and over to express the paths to all files. I'll update the example shortly to give any readers a better picture of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Rsync is another option:

```
rsync -axvP --remove-source-files sourcedirectory/ targetdirectory
```

This works because in rsync the trailing slash matters, `sourcedirectory/` refers to the content of the directory, while `sourcedirectory` would refer to the directory itself.

The disadvantage of this method is that rsync will only cleanup the files after the move, not the directory. So you are left with an empty sourcedirectory tree. For workarounds for that, see:

[Move files and delete directories with rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78375/move-files-and-delete-directories-with-rsync)

So while this might not be optimal for move operations, it can be extremely useful for copy operations.

Answer (score 2):

Try the copy command `cp`:

```
$ cp -r myfolder/* destinationfolder
```

`cp -r` means copy recursive, so all folders and files will be copied.

You can use the remove command `rm` to remove a folder:

```
$ rm -r myfolder
```

See more: [move all files from a directory to another one](http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/514-move-all-files-from-a-directory-to-another-one).

Comment: Not the best when you're moving a lot of large files, but I guess it would work.

Comment: Maybe if you use a dot instead of the star?

Comment: Warning: this does not copy hidden files.  The asterisk * does not include hidden files by default.

Answer (score 2):

For *minimal* Linux distros, the following ought to work.  First, perform a basic move all (which misses the hidden files). Then, move all the hidden files (including the `.` and `..` which will **not** actually be moved).

```
mv /sourceDir/* /destinationDir 2> /dev/null
mv /sourceDir/.* /destinationDir 2> /dev/null
```

**Notes:** If there is no visible content, the first command will produce an error message.  The second command will **always** produce an error saying it can't move `.` and `..`.  As such, just pipe the errors into `/dev/null` (as shown).

If you need this as a one-liner, simply combine them with a semi-colon:

```
mv /sourceDir/* /destinationDir 2> /dev/null; mv /sourceDir/.* /destinationDir 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: this helped me 2> /dev/null

Comment: when combined with this 
```mv {Foo/*,Foo/.*} Bar/ 2> /dev/null
```
produces a desired result. 2> /dev/null runs that command in the background, so to ignore pipe errors on . and ..

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for bash/fish**

Here's a way to do it using wildcards:

`.[!.]* ..?*` will match **all hidden files** except `.` and `..`

`.[!.]* ..?* *` will match **all files (hidden or not)** except `.` and `..`

And to answer the particular example of this question you need `cd foo && mv .[!.]* ..?* * ../bar`

**Explanation**

`.[!.]*` matches file-names starting with one dot, followed by any character except the dot *optionally* followed by any string. This is close enough but it misses files starting with two dots like `..foo`. To include such files we add `..?*` which matches file-names starting with two dots, followed by any character, *optionally* followed by any string.

**Test**

You can test these wildcards with the commands below. I've tried them successfully under bash and fish. They fail under sh, zsh, xonsh.

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
touch  a  .b  .bc  ..c  ..cd  ...d  ...de
ls .[!.]* ..?*
# you get this output:
          .b  .bc  ..c  ..cd  ...d  ...de
# cleanup
cd ..
rm -rf temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to find and grep with backquotes to select files for the move command.  Pass those into mv.

I.e.  For hidden files

```
find Foo -maxdepth 1 | egrep '^Foo/[.]' # Output: .hidden
```

So

```
mv `find Foo -maxdepth 1 | egrep '^Foo/[.]'` Bar # mv Foo/.hidden Bar
```

Moves only selected hidden files into `Bar`:

```
mv `find Foo -maxdepth 1 | egrep '^Foo/.'` Bar # mv Foo/.hidden Foo/notHidden Bar
```

Moves all files in Foo to Bar since the '.' in the egrep command acts as a wildcard without the square brackets.

The `^` character ensures the match starts from the beginning of the line.

Some details of `egrep` pattern matching can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/egrep-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Using `maxdepth 1` stops find from going into subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/156003/328505):

Without copying the files...

```
rsync -ax --link-dest=../Foo/ Foo/ Bar
```

Caveats:

- `--link-dest` path must be absolute or relative to DESTINATION (`Bar`
  in the example)
- You've to put `/` after SOURCE (`Foo/` in the example), otherwise it 
  will copy the SOURCE folder instead of contents of it.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

This is the most reliable method. It can digest any number of files:

`find folder2 -name '*.*' -exec mv {} folder \;`

`-exec` runs any command, `{}` inserts the filename found, `\;` marks the end of the exec command.

Thanks to Karl Bielefeldt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942473/4845952