# restricting pushes to selected Mercurial repositories using `ssh` forced commands and `hg-ssh`

Tags: bash, ssh, wildcards, dot-files, mercurial

The context of this question is the [`hg-ssh`](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/raw-file/tip/contrib/hg-ssh) script. It is helpful but not critical to know something about [Mercurial](http://selenic.com/mercurial/wiki). This script sets up a forced command using public keys so the given public key setup on the server will only allow the owner of the corresponding private key to push to a permitted set of repositories on the server. This forced commands is usually prefixed to the public key in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. With regard to this permitted set, the documentation before the script in the link above says:

```
You can use pattern matching of your normal shell, e.g.:
command="cd repos && hg-ssh user/thomas/* projects/{mercurial,foo}"
```

The idea is to permit only pushing to repositories on the server that match this pattern. I've been using `hg-ssh` with the forced command

```
command="cd /srv/hg && /usr/local/bin/hg-ssh * */* */*/* */*/*/*",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa [...]
```

to match all repositories (up to some number of path components) under `/srv/hg`, using shell globbing. I belatedly realized that it is *not* matching paths which contain components starting with `.`. My current non-working example is the [MQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) repository `/srv/hg/faheem/bixfile/.hg/patches`. So, my question is, 
can I select a pattern that corresponds to *all* paths? I would prefer to use shell globbing, which are less of a headache than regular expressions in general, but I'd take a regular expression if globbing is not an option.

Comment: I was kindly pointed to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-do-you-move-all-files-including-hidden-in-a-directory-to-another by [Gilles](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles). I wonder if sticking in a `shopt -s dotglob` before the command would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recursive matching, the right tool is often `find`. Since you want to match all files in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively, but only down to a certain depth, specify `-maxdepth`. This isn't in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html), but exists on all current *BSD and in GNU find (Linux, Cygwin) and in Busybox (embedded Linux) so it's a safe bet that you have it. `-exec … {} +` is a relatively recent addition to POSIX, but it's been in GNU and FreeBSD/NetBSD/OSX for a while now.

```
cd /srv/hg && find . -type d -maxdepth 3 -exec /usr/local/bin/hg-ssh {} +
```

(I added `-type d` because you seem to want to match directories only, even though your attempt with `* */*` etc. matches files of all types.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. How would this look exactly, in the context of the script as posted above, ie `command="cd /srv/hg && /usr/local/bin/hg-ssh * */* */*/* */*/*/*",no-port-forwarding,...`? Does everything up to the curly brackets go inside the `command`? Also, really, the idea is to match only the directories, not the files, since a repository can only correspond to a directory, and not a file.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Everything, from `cd` to `+`, is the shell command. I copied what you did, matching all files regardless of type. If you want to match only directories, add `-type d` before `-exec`. But I wonder if this is really what you want (note that I know nothing about `hg-ssh`): are you looking for `.hg` directories?

Comment: No, all directories are possible Mercurial repositories. The example I gave (`/srv/hg/faheem/bixfile/.hg/patches`) is the special case of a MQ repository, which lives inside the `.hg` directory corresponding to another Mercurial repository. I tried it and got `remote: find: Expected a positive decimal integer argument to -mindepth, but got '-maxdepth'.` Can one just leave mindepth out, or does it need to be given a number?

Comment: It works if I take out `-mindepth`, but does it then default to `mindepth` 1? I'm currently using `command="cd /srv/hg && find . -maxdepth 4 -type d -exec /usr/local/bin/hg-ssh {} +"`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I meant `-mindepth 1` to exclude `.` (depth 0), but I guess you want to include it? So no `-mindepth`.

Comment: Well, any directory under `/srv/hg` is a possible match. So, level 0 would correspond to matching `/srv/hg/foo` for some directory `foo`, yes? And excluding `mindepth` means depth goes from 0 up? BTW, can you add a link to the `-exec … {} +` syntax, please? Thanks.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Depth 0 is what you pass to `find`, here `.` (which is `/srv/hg`). Depth 1 is `./*`, depth 2 is `./*/*`, etc. So `/srv/hg/foo` is at depth 1 here. I've added a link to the POSIX spec of `find`.

Comment: Ok, then I guess I want searches at depth 1 and lower.