# How does ssh pick which key to use?

Tags: ssh, mercurial

I'm using the following as a forced command with [hg-ssh](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/file/e9725e18bdf8/contrib/hg-ssh).

This forced command is designed to just allow pushes with hg. However, I must be doing something wrong, because I can actually log in with this key. I've used this for a while, and my recollection is that it used to exit immediately if I used this key to try to log in.

I have this following in `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

```
command="cd /srv/hg/faheem && find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 4 -type d -exec /usr/bin/hg-ssh {} +",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa public_key
```

This may have an obvious answer, but I don't even know what the shell command

```
cd /srv/hg/faheem && find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 4 -type d -exec /usr/bin/hg-ssh {} +
```

is doing, exactly.

Stack Exchange automatically produced [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16019/4671) that I asked in 2011 and forgot about, so it looks like I got this command from [this answer of @Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16023/4671).

**UPDATE:** I have two keys for the same local-remote combination. One of these is set up as a regular key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I.e. it looks like

```
ssh-rsa public_key
```

The other is as given above. The regular key is listed first, and the forced-command key second in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. From the output of `ssh -vvv` the "regular" key is being used. Here are the relevant stanzas client-side in `.ssh/config`.

```
Host ramnode
Hostname xx.x.xxx.xxx
ForwardX11 yes

Host ramnode_hg
Hostname xx.x.xxx.xxx
ForwardX11 yes
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bulldog_hg
```

The first is the "regular" key, the second is the forced-command key.

Perhaps it is not possible to specify which key should be used, and that ssh just tries keys in order in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` till something works.

**UPDATE 2:** Having tried switching the order of the keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, with the forced-command key first, this appears to not be the case. Doing

```
ssh ramnode_hg
```

still logs me in to the machine.

**UPDATE 3:** The output of `ssh -vvv` when logging into the machine.

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/faheem/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/faheem/.ssh/config line 122: Applying options for ramnode_hg
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.x.xxx.xxx [xx.x.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa_bulldog_hg" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa_bulldog_hg type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa_bulldog_hg-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "xx.x.xxx.xxx" from file "/home/faheem/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/faheem/.ssh/known_hosts:68
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 4e:66:01:8f:a1:44:f6:d9:01:e4:72:ff:6a:ab:8e:31
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "xx.x.xxx.xxx" from file "/home/faheem/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/faheem/.ssh/known_hosts:68
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'xx.x.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/faheem/.ssh/known_hosts:68
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f81f0ca2550)
debug2: key: /home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa_bb (0x7f81f0ca23b0)
debug2: key: /home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa_bulldog_hg (0x7f81f0c9d590)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp a1:78:e9:c1:f4:9c:5e:23:a3:d9:38:35:be:0a:b4:8b
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA a1:78:e9:c1:f4:9c:5e:23:a3:d9:38:35:be:0a:b4:8b
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xx.x.xxx.xxx ([xx.x.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env FULLNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env KDE_MULTIHEAD
debug3: Ignored env DM_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env XDM_MANAGED
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env GTK2_RC_FILES
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env CVSROOT
debug3: Ignored env GS_LIB
debug3: Ignored env GTK_RC_FILES
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env SHELL_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env KDE_FULL_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env HISTFILESIZE
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env COLUMNS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env PSQL_EDITOR
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env KDE_SESSION_UID
debug3: Ignored env PYTHONSTARTUP
debug3: Ignored env KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GPG_TTY
debug3: Ignored env CVS_SSH
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env KDE_SESSION_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env XCURSOR_THEME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS
debug3: Ignored env EMAIL
debug3: Ignored env PROMPT_COMMAND
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env ALTERNATE_EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env PROFILEHOME
debug3: Ignored env QT_PLUGIN_PATH
debug3: Ignored env RSYNC_RSH
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux faheem 2.6.32-042stab079.6 #1 SMP Mon Aug 26 19:47:50 MSK 2013 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Apr 10 01:43:43 2014 from [localhost]
```

**UPDATE 4:** I have an ssh agent running, and ssh-add -L confirms it has keys loaded.

Comment: The command executes `hg-ssh`, passing files under `/srv/hg/faheem` as arguments. Is that the only line in `.ssh/authorized_keys`? Does `public_key` stand for a base64 string that starts with `AAAA`?

Comment: Hi Gilles. No, that is not the only line in `.ssh/authorized_keys`. There is one other, but that is not a forced-command key. Yes, the public key in question does start with `AAAA`. What is the significance of that?

Comment: Just checking that the file is well-formed. Is the `AAAA…` part different in the two lines?

Comment: Yes, the two public key strings are different for the two lines.

Comment: Removing the non-forced-command key/line from `.ssh/authorized_keys` makes the forced-command key behave correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't sending the non-forced-command key? Do you use ssh-agent or similar? Post the trace from `ssh -vv …`.

Comment: It looks like it is using the non-forced-command key. Further comments in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *client* picks which key to send. In fact, you can see that in your verbose client output:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/faheem/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
```

The client offered to prove its identity with that key (the client picked this key because its the first one in its list of default key locations for protocol 2 that exists, the full list is in the ssh(1) manpage), so the server checked the authorized_keys file. It found the key is authorized, so it said OK. Then the client went ahead and proved its identity with the key:

```
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp a1:78:e9:c1:f4:9c:5e:23:a3:d9:38:35:be:0a:b4:8b
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA a1:78:e9:c1:f4:9c:5e:23:a3:d9:38:35:be:0a:b4:8b
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xx.x.xxx.xxx ([xx.x.xxx.xxx]:22).
```

By default, when you specify `IdentityFile`, it just gives files to search in addition to anything already loading in ssh-agent (which you can check by running `ssh-add -l` or `ssh-add -L`). To tell it to *only* use the files you specify, you must also add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to your config.