# copy directory into another directory multiple times

Tags: shell-script, cp

I'm on a Mac and trying to script out a few things from our build for Xcode. There are `dSYM` that are directories that you can inspect with `Show package contents`. In my script that gets run after Xcode builds, I try to copy a dSYM to the output directory.

my command is this:

```
cp -vR "${BUILD_PATH}/${CONFIGURATION}-${DEVICE_TYPE}/${FRAMEWORK}.dSYM" "${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/${FRAMEWORK}.dSYM"
```

Expanded that would basically look like

```
cp -vR "${BUILD_PATH}/${ANOTHER_FOLDER}/MyFramework.framework.dSYM" "${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/MyFramework.framework.dSYM"
```

What happens is I get my dsym folder copied into the dsym folder so it looks like this:

```
MyFramework.framework.dSYM/MyFramework.framework.dSYM
```

I can `rm -rf` the dSYM before I copy it over, but was more curious if there was another way without removing it and what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the MyFramework.framework.dSYM parent folder copied in, then adjust the `cp` command so that it starts *below* that directory. To match the previous behavior, where *every* file within the dSYM directory was copied, even dot-files, you'll have to tell your shell to pick those up; with bash, it's with `shopt -s dotglob`.

The new `cp` command would be:

```
shopt -s dotglob
cp -vR "${BUILD_PATH}/${CONFIGURATION}-${DEVICE_TYPE}/${FRAMEWORK}.dSYM"/* \
       "${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/${FRAMEWORK}.dSYM"
```

Where all I've done is append `/*` to the end of the source path.

A sample run:

## setup

```
$ tree -a build_path/
build_path/
└── configuration-type
    └── framework.dSYM
        ├── a
        ├── .dotfile-here
        └── subdir
            └── b

3 directories, 3 files
```

## execution

```
cp -vR build_path/configuration-type/framework.dSYM/* output_folder/MyFramework.framework.dSYM
```

## result

```
$ tree -a output_folder/
output_folder/
└── MyFramework.framework.dSYM
    ├── a
    ├── .dotfile-here
    └── subdir
        └── b

2 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: So this copies everything underneath the dSYM directory into a new directory dSYM right? basically replaces everything if it exists? thanks.

Comment: It's the same `cp` command as you had before, it just skips that top-level dSYM directory so it doesn't get doubled-up.  The -v flag makes for verbose output, showing each file that was copied; the -R flag makes it recurse down the source directory structure.

Comment: For other shells and dotfiles, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279448/117549