# grep -ril, show only top directory once

Tags: grep

So I would like to do `grep -ril` in a folder. I would want it to return only the top folder which gets a match.

To illustrate:

`/tmp/: grep -ril "hello"`

returns:

```
tmp1/banan/file
tmp1/banan2/file
tmp2/ape/file
tmp2/ape2/file
```

Expected result:

```
tmp1
tmp2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directories don't match patterns for content; files do. What you seem to be asking is how to get the directories of files that match the pattern.

Strip off the path past the first component, and ensure the result is presented as unique values in sorted order, as you have specified

```
grep -ril "hello" | sed 's!/.*$!!' | sort -u
```

Replace the `sort` with `awk '!h[$0]++'` if you don't want to change the order of results

Comment: `grep` will scan the folders sequentially (you cannot get a result from tmp1, then another from tmp2, then back one from tmp1) so it would be better to use `uniq` instead of `sort -u`, as it won't need to keep everything in memory, and it will produce the results as they are printed

Comment: Indeed, but because `grep` searches in directory order I wanted to be sure the output could be the expected `tmp1`, `tmp2` rather than `tmp2`, `tmp1`. It would be possible to replace the `awk` with `uniq`, or the `sed` with `cut -d/ -f1`, as there are often multiple routes to a solution

Answer (score 6):

If you want to print only the first level directory, it will be more efficient to exit immediately after finding the first match under this directory. You can achieve this using `-q` which returns success for matching otherwise failure and when combined with `-r` it exits immediately when a match is found.

```
for d in */; do grep -qri "hello" -- "$d" && printf "%s\n" "$d"; done
```

`--` is used to indicate the end of options, so whatever follows is file arguments, this protects form any directory named `-something` and could be interpreted as an option.

In case you would like the above `for` to match directories starting with `.`, consider setting `shopt -s dotglob`, see also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40662/what-is-the-setting-in-bash-for-globbing-to-control-whether-matches-dot-files).

If you need to remove the trailing `/` from the output, you can use bash parameter expansion and, instead of `"$d"`, print `"${d%/}"`.