# ls -ad */ won't display hidden directories

Tags: linux, command-line, ls, command

`pwd` is my home directory. `ls */ -d` displays the directories.

```
~$ ls */ -d
Blog/  Desktop/  Documents/  Downloads/  Music/  Pictures/  Public/  Templates/  Videos/
```

And `ls -a` displays all hidden directories and files. Hidden directories - `.cache`, `.local` etc.

```
$ ls -a
.                        .cache      .gnupg       .xsession-errors.old
..                       .config     .gtkrc-2.0   Templates
.bash_history            Desktop     .gtkrc-xfce  Pictures      .themes
.bash_logout             .linuxmint   .pki          Videos
.bashrc                  Documents   .local       .profile      .viminfo
Blog                     Downloads   .mozilla     Public        .Xauthority
Music        .ssh          .xsession-errors
```

But when I run `ls -ad */`, it won't displays any hidden directories. Anyone care to explain?

```
$ ls -ad */ 
Blog/  Desktop/  Documents/  Downloads/  Music/  Pictures/  Public/  Templates/  Videos/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the setting in bash for globbing, to control whether \* matches dot files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40662/what-is-the-setting-in-bash-for-globbing-to-control-whether-matches-dot-files)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`*` **deliberately** doesn't match hidden files or directories, because most of the time that's exactly what is wanted (as dot files and directories are generally used for configuration, not data), and you can override the default by explicitly specifying a glob starting with `.` if/when you need to.

If you want them to be matched by a glob, use `ls -d .*` (or `ls -d .*/` to match only hidden directories without regular files).  To match both hidden and non-hidden directories, use `ls -d -- */ .*/`

NOTE: as mentioned by @rexkogitans in a comment, globs like `*` are expanded by the shell **before** they are passed to a program.  `ls` never sees a `*` or `.*` (or `.*/`), it sees the list of file and/or directory names that are the result of the shell expanding the glob.   This is why you need to quote or escape (by prefixing with a backslash) glob characters if you want to pass them as string literals to a program.

Also note: if there are no files/dirs matching the glob then the glob is passed to the program as is, unexpanded (i.e. `ls` will see `*` as its argument).   `bash` (and some other bourne-like shells) allow this behaviour to be over-ridden  - e.g. in bash, you can use the `nullglob` or `failglob` shell options.  nullglob causes it to be expanded to nothing (i.e. it is removed from the argument list), while failglob triggers an error.

Comment: I guess it should be pointed out that `*/` is replaced by shell globbing before command invocation. Since you have 9 unhidden directories, it is replaced by 9 respective parameters passed to `ls`. This behaviour differs from DOS and Windows, where the parameter `*/` is passed literally to the command (e.g. `dir`), and the command needs to perform the globbing.

Answer (score 16):

When you run `ls -a`, there are no filenames on the `ls` command line (as seen by `ls`), so it determines the filenames it should list by itself. Since `-a` is specified, that includes showing “hidden” files.

When you run `ls -d */` and `ls -ad */`, the shell expands `*/`, and provides the list of filenames which `ls` will show. [`*` at the start of a filename pattern doesn’t match `.`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03), so `*/` doesn’t include hidden files: in combination with `-d`, the `-a` has no effect here.

To see hidden directories, you can list them explicitly: `ls -d -- */ .*/`. In some shells, you can ask for `*` to match hidden files too; for example in Bash, with `shopt -s dotglob` (note that `.` and `..` are not included in that case which makes it behave more like `ls -A`).

Also note the `--` that you forgot to mark the end of options to make sure file names are not treated as options if they start with `-`. Also note that `*/` includes directories *and symlinks to directories*. If using `zsh`, you can do `ls -d -- *(D/)` to list directories only (including hidden ones with `D`), and without adding a trailing `/` to each file. Or `*(D-/)` if you do want the symlinks to directories.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer, which doesn’t seem to be spelled out well anywhere,
is that, in `ls`, `-a` / `-A` are ignored when you use `-d`,
because `-a` / `-A` control the way `ls` displays (lists)
the contents of directories,
and `-d` tells it *not* to list the contents of directories.