# How to move all files and folders via mv command

Tags: linux, command, rename

How can I move all files and folders from one directory to another via mv command?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Try with this:

```
mv /path/sourcefolder/* /path/destinationfolder/
```

Comment: This wouldn't include any "hidden" files (eg. `.htaccess`)

Comment: Good point. If you are using bash, then you can run `shopt -s dotglob` and then "*" will match hidden files, too.

Comment: What happens if there are folders and files with the same name in the destination folder?  Are they overwritten?

Comment: ... it seems folders with the same name are not overwritten.  `mv: cannot move '/a/js' to '/b/js': Directory not empty`

Comment: You just pass `-f` to it to overwrite

Comment: @Luka actually -f doesn't help with overwriting folders. Says the same thing. You gotta use rsync or make sure folders are empty

Comment: It does help if you use `/bin/mv -f` instead of `mv -f`.
Because `mv` is by default aliased to `-i` on some distributions.
And that's why it appears it doesn't work. 
Add this `alias cp='cp'` to `~/.bash_aliases` to fix it.

Comment: @trainoasis so sorry, not `-f`, you should use `-r`. But the same applies to alias if it's aliased it won't work properly.

Comment: To move the current dir content - **mv ./* ../another_folder**

Answer (score 39):

zsh:

```
mv /src/*(D) /dst/
```

`(D)` to include dot-files.

Comment: Syntax error on (D)  Why??

Comment: @Pathros, probably because you'd not doing doing it in `zsh`.

Comment: I know I accepted the first answer many years ago, and it's stupid for me now to change it. But actually, I've been always using this method.

Answer (score 21):

This works for me in Bash (I think this depends on your shell quite a bit...)

```
$  mv source/{,.}* /destination/folder/here
```

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't since in Bash `source/{,.}*` matches dir-entries named `./` and `../`

Comment: When I try I get `mv: overwrite 'destination/.'? mv: overwrite 'destination/..'?`, but adding `-n` to `mv` stops it from trying to overwrite

Comment: @Putnik - that's a good gotcha!  what os/distro ?  ( I was working on OSX when I was messing around with this...)

Comment: @Niall Byrne - I see the same prompt as Putnik. Using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me in Bash 4.2.46, it moves all files and folders including hidden files and folders to another directory

```
mv /sourcedir/{,.[^.]}* /destdir/
```

Notice that .[^.]* means all hidden files except . and ..

Comment: `.[^.]*` (or its POSIX equivalent `.[!.]*`) also excludes `..anything` files.

Comment: It works in `tcsh` too.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402856/93768 contains the full correct expression.

Comment: It says "directory not empty" in for my `.git` folder

Comment: using an example with the same folder name to avoid contents copying over into a parent directory `mv /mnt/data/home/USERX/folderY/{,.[^.]}* /home/USERX/folderY`

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's a bit boring, but really bullet-proof (GNU) way is:

`cd /SourceDir && find ./ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec mv -t /Target/Dir {} +`

P. S. Now you can possibly see why lots of people do prefer Midnight Commander, though.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to do a cut and paste-like action there is a simple way that worked for me:

```
$mv /media/dir_source $HOME/Documents/
```

It will move the folder named `dir_source` located in `/media` to the directory `$HOME/Documents/`

Answer (score -2):

yet another way just for the heck of it (because I love convoluted ways to do things I guess)

```
cd /source
for f in $(\ls -QA); do eval mv $f /destination/$f; done
```

the `-Q` and the `-A` are not POSIX, however the `-A` is fairly prevalent, and to not use the `-Q` you need to change the IFS (which then means you don't need the eval but need to quote the variable)

```
IFS="
" && for f in $(ls -A); do mv "$f" /destination/"$f"; done
```

Comment: `ls -Q` doesn't output in a format that is suitable to use with `eval` or even `$(...)`. Try after having run `touch '$(reboot)'` for instance (or `touch '$(uname)'` for a milder version).

Comment: `-A` is now POSIX (since POSIX.1-2008).