# trying to combine find command with ls -lt

Tags: find, directory, ls

I am trying to find the top 5 most recent directories that have been modified with certain permissions.

My find command is like this

```
find -d -perm -a+rwx
```

I’m trying to combine it with

```
ls -lt
```

to take the results of find and put them in a long list with the most recently modified file on top.

Nothing I tried worked; I ended up getting something saying total=0.

Comment: what version of find are you using?  Are you sure you don't want `-type d` instead of `-d`?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

zsh-ixly:

```
ls -ltd -- **/*(/omf777[1,5])
```

This performs an `ls` (a `l` long listing, again sorted by modification time `t`, and with the `-d` flag to list only the directory and not its contents) on the first 5 (`[1,5]`) files returned by the recursive [zsh glob pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) that matches directories (`/`) with 777 permissions (`f777`), ordered by modification time (`om`).

Note that hidden files and directories are ignored. Add the `D` glob qualifier to consider them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stat` instead of `ls`. I.e.:

```
find . -type d -perm -a+rwx -exec stat -c "%Y %n" '{}' ';' | sort -rn | tail -n 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Bash (or Zsh) and GNU tools installed, you can handle literally any filename:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    printf '%q\n' "${REPLY#* }"
done 9< <(
  find . -type d -perm -a+rwx -printf '%T@ %p\0' |
    sort --general-numeric-sort --zero-terminated |
    head --lines=5 --zero-terminated)
```

Reading outside in, this does the following:

1. Find directories which are open to the world.
2. For each directory, print the modification timestamp and file path followed by a NUL character.
3. Sort the list numerically, that is, according to the timestamp since that is the first column.
4. Get the first five zero-terminated entries.
5. Read this list one by one.
6. Strip the timestamp from each entry.
7. Print a quoted version of each filename.

Answer (score -1):

`find` is traditionally/conventionally paired with `xargs`:

`find …something… -print0 | xargs -0 …dosomething…`

Specifically to your q-n piping should be done to `xargs -0 ls -dlt`

☝️Note: BSDs'<sup>1</sup> version of `xargs` won't run if there were no input piped; but with GNU you'd better use `-r` (`man xargs` would reveal)

__

1 — As indicated in comments OpenBSD is an exception (as it's often the case w/ OpenBSD) ;)

Comment: That depends on which BSD. That's true of FreeBSD or NetBSD, but not of OpenBSD or macOS IIRC (POSIX `xargs` does require the command to be run once upon empty input and doesn't specify the `-r` nor `-0` options). Using `-exec cmd {} +` is a more standard/reliable way to run `cmd` with as many of the files _found_ by `find` as possible with each invocation.

Comment: • `find`'s `exec`-and-company are things known to me long ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50523/6622
• Moreover, I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs
• _Also_, you'd better check manual and _avoid using_ `-exec` preferring `-execdir` instead (when you're inclined to avoid `xargs` anyways)

Comment: So, in remainder your note goes to "OpenBSD also has -r". _macOS does not though_. Added to answer.

Comment: To clarify, I was not the one downvoting. The fact that find and xargs are often used together (even though without the non-standard -0/-print0 that's not reliable), that you generally want `-r` where available (and need to resort to things like `xargs -0 sh -c '[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec cmd "$@"' sh` otherwise) are good points. See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697). Note that `-execdir` is not portable/standard yet and on BSDs has issues of its own.

Comment: Well, actually `-r` is implied with BSD's version in despite of being absent there, so no need for SHELL wrap arounds. `-r` is needed only on GNU version and OpenBSD's as you noted. One might use `ifne` BTW. As to `-execdir` well, I by myself did prefer all those `-exec`'s until becoming more familiar with `xargs`. I don't think your point on `-print0`/`-0` makes any sense; any modern UNIX-like has support for it. Even OpenBSD does. ;-P

_To clarify, I was not the one downvoting._ — thanks, but I think it's nevermind anyways.