# Backing up data to two drives

Tags: backup

I am currently working on backing up an inactive users data from a server. The data is roughly 7tb. For the backup task, I have two four TB drives.

So what is a reasonable way to move the data into the two drives?

I thought of creating a single volume spanning the two, but for archival purposes keeping them independent seems better.

Comment: I think `rsync` is a nice idea, since when a file is successfully copied, it can remove it from the source directory. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78375/move-files-and-delete-directories-with-rsync

Comment: Yup. Rsync is a neat tool. I used it with ncdu to find then folders under 3.6TB and moved them to disks.